# After Update in Apex Class - Total Contacts "Roll-Up Summary"

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex-trigger, salesforce-development

I added the Apex Class and Apex trigger below to update the field Number_of_Contacts at the Account level when a Contact is added or removed to a certain Account.

My idea is to display in Accounts reports, how many Contacts an Account has. I had to do this, because Salesforce doesn't provide a Roll-Up Summary, at the Account level, to count Contacts.

I also tried creating a Flow, but it only works when a Contact is created or deleted.

Here are Apex Class and Trigger I tried to use:

Class:

```
public without sharing class  ContactTriggerHandler {
    
   private Set<Id> getAccountIds(List<Contact> contacts) {
       
       Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
       
        for(Contact c : contacts) {
            if(c.AccountId != null) {
                accountIds.add(c.AccountId);
            }
        }
        
        return accountIds;
   }
    
   private Map<Id, Account> getAccountMap(Set<Id> accountIds) {
       
       return new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Number_of_Contacts__c FROM Account WHERE Id in :accountIds]);
   }
   public void process(List<Contact> contacts, System.TriggerOperation operation) {
       
       Set<Id> accountIds = getAccountIds(contacts);
        
        if(accountIds.size() > 0) {
            Map<Id, Account> accountMap = getAccountMap(accountIds);
            
            for(Contact c : contacts) {
                if(accountMap.containsKey(c.AccountId)) {
                    switch on operation{
                        when AFTER_INSERT {
                            accountMap.get(c.AccountId).Number_of_Contacts__c += 1;
                        }
                        when AFTER_DELETE {
                            accountMap.get(c.AccountId).Number_of_Contacts__c -= 1;
                        }
                        when AFTER_UNDELETE {
                            accountMap.get(c.AccountId).Number_of_Contacts__c += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            update accountMap.values();
        }
       
   }


}
```

Trigger

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (after insert, after delete, after undelete) {
    
    ContactTriggerHandler handler = new ContactTriggerHandler();
    switch on Trigger.operationType {
        when AFTER_INSERT {
            handler.process(Trigger.new, Trigger.operationType);
        }
        when AFTER_DELETE {
            handler.process(Trigger.old, Trigger.operationType);
        }
        when AFTER_UNDELETE {
            handler.process(Trigger.new, Trigger.operationType);
        }
    }
    
}
```

However, how can I include a line of code that updates the Number_of_Contacs__c field when a Contact moves to a different Account (like, an "After_Update" trigger)?

Thank you,

I tried some guidance on how to add AFTER UPDATE triggers in Apex Code, but I didn't succeed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [trigger to populate/update these field on Account record whenever a new Contact, opportunity record is inserted or deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57007779/trigger-to-populate-update-these-field-on-account-record-whenever-a-new-contact)

Comment: Probably! I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

[Trigger context variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) give you access to old and new values, state of the database before the user clicked save and what the user has changed. You're passing from trigger to class only `trigger.new` but to get the id of original account the contact was linked to and update it - something like this.

```apex
Set<Id> idsToCheck = new Set<Id>();

// During update, only if account id changes...
for(Contact c : trigger.new){
    Contact old = trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id);
    if(c.AccountId != old.AccountId){
        idsToCheck.add(c.AccountId);
        idsToCheck.add(old.AccountId); // mark both for further processing
    }
}
idsToCheck.remove(null);

List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :idsToCheck];
for(Account a : accounts){
    a.Number_of_Contacts__c = a.Contacts.size();
}
update accounts;
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting! Where should I input this trigger context variable? Should it be after the "when" clause?

Comment: Your handler.process(Trigger.new, Trigger.operationType); has "room" only for 1 list which you use to write trigger.new. you'd need to tweak it to pass also trigger.old or trigger.oldmap, not just trigger.new.

Comment: You could consider using bit more "pro" trigger handler framework which would include room for these "old" and "new" already. For simple projects I like https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework. https://github.com/mitchspano/apex-trigger-actions-framework is nice too